# Best strategy for brute-forcing a test?

Tags: probability

If you were to try to brute-force a multiple-choice test (with, say, m questions with n choices each), where you had unlimited attempts, and you received a total of how many questions you got right at the end, but where leaving an answer blank isn't allowed, what would be the best strategy?

The simplest way I can think of is to simply fill all As, and guess each question at a time, but that would take m*n max attempts.

Comment: See also the game [Mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29) which is closely related -- your problem is the same as Mastermind if the white feedback pegs are ignored (and only black feedback pegs are used).

Comment: I think your method is $m^{n}$ attempts (max).

Comment: @TravisJ: No, that would be the stupidmost brute-force strategy (and even that is $n^m$ rather than $m^n$). The $m\times n$ strategy starts by finding the first answer (submit all possible values of it, keeping the rest of the answers constant, and see which of your submissions has a higher score than the others). Then do the same for the second answer, and so forth. Finding the correct answer to one question never takes more than $n$ submissions (in fact $n-2$ submissions is enough except for the first one)

Comment: @HenningMakholm, ahh, I see.  I think I mis-understood the method that hintss described.

Comment: It's different in that you don't get feedback on individual questions, though.